# Insert statement with dynamic columns

Tags: t-sql

I have a table which consists of 100 columns based on a specific condition i want to generate only some of columns in insert statement.Right now my T-sql statement is hard-coded with certain columns.
eg:
The table has 100 columns but based on a condition i have insert only in specific colunms:

```
insert into temp (id,name,age,gender,contact) 
select * from #temp--temp table
```

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: can we generate columns dynamically in insert statement??

Comment: you can generate and execute dynamic sql statements and collect columns from the [all_columns-sys-table](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms177522.aspx) for example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a fully working example:

```
create table temp (id int,name varchar(20),code int, morecolumns int) 
create table #temp(id int,name varchar(20),code int)

insert #temp values(1,'Thomas Clausen',1)

select * into xx_temp from #temp

declare @col varchar(max) , @sql varchar(max) = ''

select @col = coalesce(@col + ',', '')+ '[' + name + ']'
from tempdb.sys.columns 
where object_id = object_id('tempdb..#temp');

select @sql='insert temp(' + @col+ ') select '+@col+' from xx_temp'  

exec (@sql)
go
drop table xx_temp
```

There is a drawback, this example will create a table xx_temp and drop it right after executing. So the script should not execute more than once at a time.
The table xx_table is created to get the data into the same scope inside the dynamic sql

Comment: Actually i pass a datatable from c# to my store procedure which may consist of only 5 columns whereas the destination table has 100 columns.how can i convert my dataset into the destination table.so that i can only insert 5 column values.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to construct the query as string (varchar) and then execute it using -

```
Exec sp_executesql
```

For Example -

```
Declare @sql varchar(max)
SET @sql = 'insert into temp '
```

Now, you can add the names of the columns into @sql variable, depending upon your logic.

Comment: @sql varchar(max)='id' is this fine

Comment: you can't assign the value while declaring variable in TSQL. You can do this - @Sql varchar(max); set @Sql='id'

Comment: @Umesh actually you can from sqlserver 2008+

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to specify the columns you can do select into

```
SELECT * 
INTO newTable
FROM #source
```

This will do what you wanted but `newTable` table must not exist (this query will create the table).
If you want to insert into existing you must specify the columns, and I'm sorry to say but EXEC of generated string query is the only way to do it.